# Jenkins with incremental Gradle build of multi module project for continuous delivery

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a multi module Gradle build that is in a GITHUB repo with the following layout:

```
<top level>
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle
-- <WAR 1>
-- <WAR 2>
-- <ZIP 1>
-- <ZIP 2>
-- <SHARED JAR 1>
-- <SHARED JAR 2>
```

Both the WAR and ZIP artifacts use the shared JAR's.

This builds fine with Gradle and works well with incremental builds.

My issue is when I create a Jenkins job to build the artifacts, I only want to version and save artifacts that have had changes. This means that if I make a change to WAR 1, then only WAR 1 should be built (Gradle builds this fine with incremental support) and Jenkins should only either archive WAR 1 or push to artifact repo with a new version.

Currently I can only get Jenkins to always archive all WAR, ZIP's and JAR's.

I'm trying to get a continuous delivery pipeline developed with this setup and in turn avoid using SNAPSHOT's, each artifact will be versioned and ready for production.

Any idea's would be great, thanks.

Comment: I think it will be easier for support, tech ops, people who deploy, and everyone if you were to make your artifacts all come out with the same version, so you have version 1.2.3 to deploy to prod. It will then give your developers the ability to easily track down changes and fix them. Since the builds won't recompile and test everything it shouldn't be a build time hit.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan, currently that is what we have come to do. I did develop a script in Jenkins to tell which downstream job to kick off but this did start to make the pipeline confusing.